# How to use IPv6 tunnel to allow a dynamic IP in (Windows) firewall

Tags: windows, firewall, ipv6, tunnel

I am frequently changing locations and my client has to update their firewall rules to allow me access to various servers when my IP changes.

I'm looking for a better solution. A couple of things that I'm investigating are:

- using a VPN
- using a dynamic hostname and a powershell script to update the firewall rules

One intriguing suggestion is to use an IPv6 tunnel. My understanding is that it works similar to a dynamic hostname. I register for the IPv6 address and set up a tunnel to my (current) IPv4 address. My client then adds the IPv6 address to the firewall and viola, I have access.

Does this make sense? If so, can anyone provide a guide on how to configure it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah sure it can completely work, if you find a tunnel broker (e.g.: [tunnelbroker.net](http://tunnelborker.net)) who support dynamic client IP updates. The methodology is changes with providers, at [tunnelborker.net](http://tunnelborker.net) they give you a link, sending a request to this url will update your client IP.
But make sure, your client (where you want to set the firewall up) also has IPv6 access.